# How to avoid the empty lines before and after a verbatim environment in a tabular cell

Tags: tables, verbatim

I want to insert some raw text and used verbatim in the cell of a tabular.

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{p{0.45\textwidth}|p{0.45\textwidth}}
\hline column 1:  &  column 2:   \\ 
\hline
\begin{verbatim}
verbatim 1
 verbatim 2
\end{verbatim}&
\begin{verbatim}
verbatim 1
 verbatim 2
\end{verbatim}\\
\hline
normal 1& normal 2\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Here is the output:

[image]

There are a empty line before and after the verbatim text...

How can I remove those empty lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fancyvrb` package provides a `BVerbatim` environment which has no space around the enclosed material:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\begin{document}
\showoutput
\begin{tabular}{p{0.45\textwidth}|p{0.45\textwidth}}
\hline column 1:  &  column 2:   \\ 
\hline
\begin{BVerbatim}
verbatim 1
 verbatim 2
\end{BVerbatim}
&
\begin{BVerbatim}
verbatim 1
 verbatim 2
\end{BVerbatim}
\\
\hline
normal 1& normal 2\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use \verb|text| instead of \begin{verbatim} \end{verbatim}

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{p{0.45\textwidth}|p{0.45\textwidth}}
\hline column 1:  &  column 2:   \\ 
\hline
\verb|verbatim 1|

\verb|verbatim 2|&
\verb|verbatim 1|

\verb|verbatim 2|\\
\hline
normal 1& normal 2\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```